# How To get XML response with Pychrome

Tags: python, xml, response

I've created a simple program that listens all chrome's requests, and prints them on screen. I can't use standard Python methods, since the websites I work on are swf. I just cannot get any response. I've tried with the library "requests" and "requests_xml" without success. Here is a little bit of my script

```
import pychrome
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --ignore-certificate-errors --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs --test-type  --remote-debugging-port=9222')
browser = pychrome.Browser(url="http://127.0.0.1:9222")
tab = browser.new_tab()


def request_will_be_sent(**kwargs):
    print("loading: %s" % kwargs.get('request').get('url'))


tab.Network.requestWillBeSent = request_will_be_sent

tab.start()

tab.Network.enable()

tab.Page.navigate(url="mysite", _timeout=5)
```

Could you help me figure out how to get a response using this library?